# In Google Sheets, how do I filter based on the value of another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, filtering, google-sheets-formula

This might seem like a simple question, but I'm really struggling to get it to work. Google Sheets has 'filter by condition', so I'm hoping I can enter the condition of a cell value in order to filter on rows with only that value.

So for example, in a column called Manager, I would like to filter by condition from another tab on cell `=Sheet1!A2`, where this is the manager name. However, it's only pulling through rows where the cell is blank.

Does anyone know how this could work, or even if it's meant to work the way I would like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is filter view not `FILTER` formula then you need to use `INDIRECT` because you refer to value on another sheet. try:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2")
```